# Pasar el where como parámetro en procedimiento Oracle

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, plsql

Tengo un ejercicio, que debo pasar el where de un select como parámetro, se os ocurre alguna idea??
Ejercicio:
/*5 - Crea un procedimiento que permita consultar todos los
datos de la tabla depart a partir de una condición que
se indicará en la llamada al procedimiento.*/

Código (que el cursor no me devuelve nada)

```
create or replace procedure ejert1005(p_condicion varchar2 ,p_valor varchar2) is

cursor c_ejercicio5 is
select * 
from depart 
WHERE p_condicion = p_valor;

v_almacen c_ejercicio5%rowtype;
v_dept_no DEPART.DEPT_NO%type;
v_dnombre DEPART.DNOMBRE%type;
v_loc DEPART.LOC%type;

BEGIN 

-- abrimos el cursor
open c_ejercicio5;

-- y almacenamos el resultado del select en la variable
fetch c_ejercicio5 into v_almacen;

-- mientras haya datos recorremos el bucle
WHILE c_ejercicio5%FOUND LOOP

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Numero de departamento: ' || v_almacen.dept_no);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nombre de departamento: ' || v_almacen.dnombre);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Localidad de departamento: ' || v_almacen.loc);

  fetch c_ejercicio5 into v_almacen;
end loop;

-- cerramos cursor
close c_ejercicio5;
END;

exec ejert1005('LOC','SEVILLA'); -- le intento decir que la columna LOC (localidad) es igual a sevilla, que me muestre todos los datos de los departamento de dicha localidad
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la condición la pasas como un varchar2, entonces me parece que vas a tener que usar un cursor dinámico.

El cursor que escribiste espera que la tabla depart tenga un campo que se llama p_condicion con un dato guardado igual al string que recibis por parametro.

Buscá en Google sobre cursores dinámicos (ref_cursors).

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el compañero Juan, podrías usar un ref_cursor al que le pasas la sentencia que quieras ejecutar como varchar, el cual compones previamente:

```
create or replace procedure ejert1005(p_condicion varchar2 ,p_valor varchar2) is

v_sentencia VARCHAR2(500);
cursor_sent SYS_REFCURSOR;


BEGIN 

v_sentencia := 'select * from depart WHERE ' || p_condicion || ' = ' || p_valor;

OPEN cursor_sent FOR v_sentencia;

--A PARTIR DE AQUI EL CODIGO SERÍA EL MISMO
```

Ponle el tamaño al varchar que creas correcto según el tamaño de la condición que vayas a usar.

Algo de mas información [aquí](https://community.oracle.com/thread/888365).